# Using variables in sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, ipconfig

I'm a n00b trying to return my IP address to a variable, which is then used in the sed command within a bash script. I'm trying to replace the text 'mycomputer' in a file with my IP address without much luck.

Here are my attempts:

## 1

```
localip=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
sed -i '' “s/mycomputer/$localip/” config.txt
```

The error I receive is:

```
sed: 1: "“s/mycomputer/192.168 ...": invalid command code ?
```

## 2

```
localip=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
sed -i '' 's/mycomputer/$localip/g' config.txt
```

Changes 'mycomputer' to '$localip' - not the actual IP address

## 3

```
localip=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
sed -i '' 's/mycomputer/‘“$localip”’/g’ config.txt
```

Error:

```
./mytest.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./mytest.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any thoughts?!?!

**Edit**:

This is for use in a bash script, as per below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "`dirname "$0"`"
localip=`ipconfig getifaddr en0’
sed -i '' "s/mycomputer/$localip/" config.txt
```

Comment: Dn't use `“”’` quotes. they're not 'quotes' as far as the shell is concerned. e.g. don't use a wordprocessor as your code editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the double-quotes wrong:

> ```
> sed -i '' “s/mycomputer/$localip/” config.txt
> ```

This should work (notice the difference):

```
sed -i '' "s/mycomputer/$localip/" config.txt
```

Actually you have similar problems on other lines too. So the full script, corrected:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd $(dirname "$0")
localip=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
sed -i '' "s/mycomputer/$localip/" config.txt
```

Note that `-i ''` is for the BSD version of `sed` (in BSD systems and MAC). In Linux, you'd write the same thing this way:

```
sed -i "s/mycomputer/$localip/" config.txt
```

Comment: thanks for this, not sure about the curly double quotes and where they came from. Your answer is still returning errors here. Maybe my shell script is the issue:

#!/bin/bash

    cd "`dirname "$0"`"
    localip=`ipconfig getifaddr en0’
    sed -i '' "s/mycomputer/$localip/" config.txt

Error is: ./mytest.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
./mytest.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: The formatting doesn't come out right in comments. Add that inside your question and I can have a look. Are you in Linux or what OS?

Comment: aaagghh fixed it with your help! I re-edited with the wrong type of quote.. of course.. never knew about the standard vs curly single and double quotes.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try using

You are doing a substitution so there is no need to `sed -i ''` and try using the shell default quotes `"`

if you are using sed **in a script** just enclose the variable `$localip` with double qoutes so that bash can do the substitution.

```
sed -i s/mycomputer/"$localip"/ config.txt
```